# JQuery Tabla con función de eliminar

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla con un campo de eliminar, mi problema es que a la hora de agregar una nueva fila y al desear eliminar esa nueva, no me deja. En cambio las filas que ya están definidas en el código html, esas si las puedo eliminar, pero las nuevas la página se me va hasta el principio y no se elimina. También tengo que implementar la función de *editar*, de la cual no tengo idea de cómo hacerla.

[image: Así es la página]

***HTML:***

```
<input type="text" id="pendiente"/>
                <input type="date" id="fecha"/>
                <input type="button" value="agregar" id="boton_agregar">
                <table id="table-pendientes">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>Pendiente</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="#" class="eliminar">Eliminar</a></td>
                            <td>Comer </td>
                            <td>2019-08-11</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="#" class="eliminar">Eliminar</a></td>
                            <td>Bañarme</td>
                            <td>2019-01-29</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

***JQuery de Agregar:***

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#boton-agregar').on('click',function(){
        var pendiente = $('#pendiente').val();
        var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
        if(pendiente !=='' && fecha !==''){
            var fila = '<tr><td><a href="#" class="eliminar">Eliminar</a></td><td>'+pendiente+'</td><td>'+fecha+'</td></tr>'
            $('#table-pendientes tbody').append(fila);
            $('#pendiente', '#fecha').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

***JQuery de Eliminar:***

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('.eliminar').on('click',function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(window.confirm("¿Desea eliminar?")){
          $(this).closest('#table-pendientes tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Para el editar te recomiendo que si te funciona la respuesta que te den abras una nuevo, ya que son 2 cosas diferentes que quieres hacer

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, en una hora publicaré la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primera tu variable llamada tarea no existe, después debes de declarar tu evento de eliminar a nivel documento para que detecte los botones que fueron creados dinamicamente, y al presionarlos detecte el evento, el código quedaría algo así:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#boton_agregar').on('click',function(){
        var pendiente = $('#pendiente').val();
        var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
        if(pendiente !=='' && fecha !==''){
            var fila = '<tr><td><a href="#" class="eliminar">Eliminar</a></td><td>'+pendiente+'</td><td>'+fecha+'</td></tr>'
            $('#table-pendientes tbody').append(fila);
            $('#pendiente', '#fecha').val('');
        }
    });
    
   $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(window.confirm("¿Desea eliminar?")){
          $(this).closest('#table-pendientes tr').remove();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pendiente"/>
                <input type="date" id="fecha"/>
                <input type="button" value="agregar" id="boton_agregar">
                <table id="table-pendientes">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>Pendiente</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="#" class="eliminar">Eliminar</a></td> 
                            <td>Comer </td>
                            <td>2019-08-11</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="#" class="eliminar">Eliminar</a></td>
                            <td>Bañarme</td>
                            <td>2019-01-29</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias :) sos un genio, ya me sale

Comment: Entonces no te sirvió mi respuesta?, creo que la mía realmente funciona. @Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

Para la parte de eliminar las nuevas solo debes hacer unos pequeños cambios en tu codigo por ejemplo encapsula el listener de tu codigo de eliminar en una función para que puedas usarlo en el de agregar, mas menos de esta manera te quedaria:

**JQuery de Eliminar**

```
var eliminarFun = function() {
     $('.eliminar').on('click',function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(window.confirm("¿Desea eliminar?")){
          $(this).closest('#table-pendientes tr').remove();
        }
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function(){
   eliminarFunc();
});
```

**JQuery de Agregar:**

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#boton-agregar').on('click',function(){
        var pendiente = $('#pendiente').val();
        var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
        if(tarea !=='' && fecha !==''){
            var fila = '<tr><td><a href="#" class="eliminar">Eliminar</a></td><td>'+pendiente+'</td><td>'+fecha+'</td></tr>'
            $('#table-pendientes tbody').append(fila);
            $('#pendiente', '#fecha').val('');
            // Aqui asignas el listener para que tome los nuevos botones de eliminar
            // creados en tu nuevo <tr>
            eliminarFunc();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias :)